# Xubuntu 12.04 Sony VGN-FJ170 Brightness/Volume/S1/S2 keys are not functional

Tags: keyboard, sony, i915

I just installed Xubuntu on an old test laptop.  None of the 'extra' function keys work.  <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>F4</kbd> = Volume control (fail), <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> = Brightness control (fail), and S1 and S2 fail to register.

The Intel GPU is the GMA900 (i915)

```
$ lsmod | grep i915

i915                  414620  3 
drm_kms_helper         45466  1 i915
drm                   197692  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
video                  19068  1 i915

$ lsmod | grep sony
sony_laptop            39681  0
```

If more info is needed, please let me know

---

Just checked `/lib/udev/keymaps/module-sony`

The keymap is correct for this FJ170 keyboard.

Comment: I just test using acpi_listen.  While holding FN and tapping F2-F12, nothing shows up.  PLEASE NOTE:  FN+F keys ARE working on Windows 7 partition.

Comment: just tried adding "acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor" to the GRUB.  Did NOT do anything with the Fn key

Comment: 'xev' did not bring up any events while pressing FN or S1/S2.  Any other keys on the keyboard did register an event

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the keyboard settings in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

There you can define which action to execute when a key or a key combination is pressed.

Comment: Uhmmm... System Settings -> Keybaord -> shortcut is for application launching...

ANYWAYZZZZ

Just check the keymaps in module_sony in /lib/udev/keymaps/ they are the right assignment to the VGN-FJ170 keys 

--------------------------------------------------------
0x06 mute # Fn+F2
0x07 volumedown # Fn+F3
0x08 volumeup # Fn+F4
0x09 brightnessdown # Fn+F5
0x0A brightnessup # Fn+F6
0x0B switchvideomode # Fn+F7
0x0E zoom # Fn+F10
0x10 suspend # Fn+F12

Comment: the shortcuts section is not only for application launching. there are also entries like volume up/down, restart etc.

Comment: if there is... I don't see it....
[Here is a screen shot](http://i50.tinypic.com/6y1w29.png)

Comment: when I hit open it only allows me to pick an application.  Plus I can't even assign a combination of keystrokes

Comment: No, I thought of [this](http://imm.io/wzzm) list.

Comment: I think that's Unity... I am using xfce.. as title stated Xubuntu 12.04